# Can't seem to extend Member Object

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm trying to extend the Member class with a DataExtension as it recommends in the docs. I've managed to attach my DataExtension to the Member class however I cannot access my newly defined methods on the Member object.

**MemberExtension.php**

```
<?php

/** 
* Extends the standard SilverStripe Member DataObject 
*/ 
class MemberExtension extends DataExtension { 
   private static $db = array( 
      'MemberExpires' => 'Date', 
      'Username' => 'Varchar' 
   );

   /** 
    * Returns the Member Object for the username specified 
    * 
    * @param $id int the username 
    * @returns Member|null the Member object or null if not found 
    */ 
   public static function getByUsername(string $username) { 
      return Member::get()->filter('Username', $username)->first(); 
   } 
}
```

I'm adding the extension in the YAML config, I do a /dev/build and the new columns appear in the DB. 
When I run `Object::get_extensions('Member')` it properly returns an array with my `MemberExtension` class.
However whenver I run `Member::getByUsername()` it always fails citing a `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Member::getByUsername()`

Am I doing this properly? 
Is their anything I'm not grasping?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Obviously that's because `getByUsername` method is not defined in `Member` class. Since you've defined it in `MemberExtension` class, you have to call it as `MemberExtension::getByUsername()`

Comment: Except for that [here](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/dataextension#additional-methods) it says that I should be able to add methods to DataObjects via DataExtensions and then access the new methods via the original DataObject.

Comment: @sonikarc your're right, but you can't add STATIC methods, just normal ones.

Comment: Oh really?

Is this something that they've changed in Silverstripe 3 because if I can remember correctly I could always do it with DataObjectDecorator's in SilverStripe 2.

Comment: @sonikarc That has always been the case. SilverStripe has never implemented the `__callStatic` method to allow an `Extension` to add static methods.

Comment: @simon_w, do you want to put your comment(s) as an answer to help other people who stumble upon this question in the future?

Comment: *Bump* @simon_w - you should write this up as an answer